Multi-page C# WPF datagrid printing: Specified element is already the logical child of another element
This error has lots of hits, but none have managed to solve my problem.  I have a datagrid running to more than one page which I want to combine into a single Fixed Document, rather than printing each page separately.  My code is from published sources but I keep getting this error, despite trying to remove the uiElement from its existing parent.
The grid I am printing contains not just the datagrid (which is concatenated so that only selected rows appear on the relevant page) but also headers and footers containing comboboxes, textboxes or textblocks, most of which are collapsed, and some of which are activated (such as a page number TextBox), for printing.
My code (after calling PrintDialog) is:
//Create FixedDocument
FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(printDlg.PrintableAreaWidth, printDlg.PrintableAreaHeight);

//Add pages
ObservableCollection<FixedPage> pages = new ObservableCollection<FixedPage>();
for (pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= lengthPages; pageNumber++)
{
    pages.Add(new FixedPage());
    //Expand PrintingGrid so that it includes all necessary datagrid rows
    grdTransactions.Height = (pageNumber == lengthPages && totalsLine) ? bdrReconciliation.Visibility == Visibility.Visible? 520: 660 : 710;//Compensate for summary box 
    if (reconciliation)
    {
        bdrReconciliation.Visibility = (totalsLine && pageNumber == lengthPages) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; //Prints summary panel on last page
    }
    else
    {
        bdrTotalsLine.Visibility = (totalsLine && pageNumber == lengthPages) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; //Prints summary panel on last page
    }
    grdPastTransactions.UpdateLayout();
    collapseHeaders(true, pageNumber, lengthPages, reconciliation);
    if (pageNumber == 1)
    {
        dgdTransactions.ItemsSource = displayTransactions.Take(firstPageLines);
        dgdTransactions.UpdateLayout();
    }
    else
    {
        dgdTransactions.ItemsSource = displayTransactions.Skip(firstPageLines + (firstPageLines * (pageNumber - 2))).Take(firstPageLines);
        dgdTransactions.UpdateLayout();
    }
    grdPastTransactions.UpdateLayout();
    if (pageRowCount < actualRowCount || (pageRowCount >= actualRowCount && totalsLine))
    {
        Grid thisGrid = new Grid();
        thisGrid = grdPastTransactions;
        UIElement uiElement = thisGrid;
        var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(thisGrid) as Grid;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.Children.Remove(uiElement);
        }
        pages[pageNumber - 1].Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
        pages[pageNumber - 1].Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
        pages[pageNumber - 1].Children.Add(thisGrid);
                    
        //Add page to document
        PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
        ((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(pages[pageNumber - 1]);
        document.Pages.Add(page1Content);
    }
    pageRowCount += pageNumber == 1 ? Math.Min(actualRowCount, firstPageLines) : 28;
}
//Print document
PrintMethods.PrintHelper.PrintNoPreview(printDlg, document);

and
public static void PrintNoPreview(PrintDialog printDialog, FixedDocument fixedDoc)
{
    try
    {
        printDialog.PrintDocument(fixedDoc.DocumentPaginator, "PMM Report");
    }
    catch (System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeWrappedException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are trying to over-write an existing PDF document of the same name which is open." +
            "\n\nPlease close the old document and try again, or save the new document with a new name.", "Save to PDF failed", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}

I have tried to add just the datagrid itself to a page, without any other elements, but get the same result. I have also tried removing the Grid (grdPastTransactions) from view with grdPastTransactions.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed before creating the Fixed Document but this also does not work.
Why can I not add pages to the Fixed Document without generating this error?  Do I need to create an entirely new Grid (with all new elements) for printing?

Your code is very inefficient. Redundant object (Grid) creation for an unnecessary variable initialization when the value is directly overwritten in the next line. But most important, you should not call UpdateLayout every two lines. You don't have to call it at all. It's very expensive. From the snippet you have posted it looks like the error is related to repeatedly adding  thisGrid to the pages. thisGrid is always set to the same value grdPastTransactions. Hence you are adding grdPastTransactions to the visual tree multiple times.

If you had posted the full context of this snippet, so that we can at least understand where all those magic variables come from then you probably would get more help. Better always post a minimal example so that we can properly review your code. Nobody knows your code. Those snippets are really useless if you ask for a review. Context really matters.

FYI grdPastTransactions.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed does not unhook the element from its parent. You would have to explicitly lift the relationship.

@SonicCode, many thanks for responding.  I don't think any further context will help as the other variables only relate to setting up the datagrid and the headers and footers.  I have tried amending the code tto remove thisGrid and identifying the parent of grdPastTransactions as the window itself in which it sits, but it still returns null.  I need to repeat grdPastTransactiions on each page as it holds the datagrid and other elements for the header and footer.  Even so, the code line pages[pageNumber - 1].Children.Add(grdPastTransactions); give the error on page 1

@SonicCode, so is there no way to assign the same Grid to each page in a Fixed Document (or, in my case, even the first page)?

"I don't think any further context will help" - It's always helpful for anybody that doesn't know what he's looking at. That this context is enough for may be correct. For me it's just annoying to look a code snippet were I don't know the method name (which also gives valuable information about what I'm looking at) and that contains magic variables. I don't question that you know what grdPastTransactions or dgdTransactions is. The point is I don't know. Nobody here can know this.

After identifying the error more context also allows the reviewer to make suggestions on changing your overall approach to avoid the error if necessary. But to make that kind of suggestion, more context is needed. A minimal reproducible example would have been great. You have a debugging problem. You can't know what's relevant or not otherwise you would not have to ask for help to identify the error. If you don't know what's relevant you have to create a minimal example instead of a minimal code snippet. I hope this makes sense from the reviewer's point of view.

"so is there no way to assign the same Grid to each page in a Fixed Document" - No.

Even if it were allowed it wouldn't make any sense and it wouldn't work. Think about it: you want to add the same instance multiple times to the visual tree. And each occurrence of the same instance is supposed to show different content. How is this supposed to work? It's the same instance. Also, removing the grid from the parent Grid is not enough. The new parent is the FixedPage. Each FixedPage has the same UIElement as child. So you have two related problems: using the same UIElement  to display multiple views and adding the same UIElement to multiple parents.

I have solved the problem of the 'Specified child is the logical child of another element' error.  As with my original single page printing, it is necessary to add the grid to a VisualBrush and then create a Canvas of the image.  This can be called iteratively to combine the pages into a single FixedDocument.
Unfortunately, I am still experiencing a problem - I create a document that contains 3, for example, copies of the last page, rather than pages 1, 2 and 3, so each iteration is over-writing the previous page(s).  As this is a new issue, I have posted my replacement code with a new question at Stackoverflow here
